# Q: Using analogRead from a potentiometer

Tags: arduino

I currently am working on a project to build a metronome using Arduino, particle photon, and a basic electrical engineering set up.

My goal for this project is to make it easy to adjust the tempo by adjusting/spinning the potentiometer and displaying the current BPM off an OLED screen. However, the problem is that when I spin the potentiometer, it's not changing the value of the tempo by anything. I know this because the buzzer isn't beeping and the OLED reads that the current BPM is 0.

```
 // This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include "SparkFunMicroOLED/SparkFunMicroOLED.h"



#define PIN_RESET D7
#define PIN_DC D6
#define PIN_CS A2

MicroOLED oled(MODE_SPI, PIN_RESET, PIN_DC, PIN_CS);


int speakerPin = D2;
int potenMeter = A4;

void setup() {
    pinMode(speakerPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(potenMeter, INPUT);
    oled.begin();
    oled.clear(ALL);

}

void loop() {

    oled.clear(PAGE);
    oled.setFontType(0);
    oled.setCursor(20,0);

    int bpm = (analogRead(potenMeter)/4095) * 180;
    tone(speakerPin, 50, 100);
    delay(bpm);


    oled.printf("BPM: %d", bpm);
    oled.display();
}
```

Whenever I flash the program to my breadboard/photon, the OLED always displays that `bpm` is equal to 0... Even if I adjust it. I'm pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the electronics as I've tested everything out separately.

Comment: Try to perform the multiplication before the division: `int bpm = (analogRead(potenMeter) * 180) / 4095;`

Comment: What @EttoreBarattelli is saying is correct. Also there are other things you might want to correct. Which Arduino are you using?

Comment: I also agree with Ettore, additionally: the Arduinos I khow just provide 10 bit ADC, a range of 1024 values ( 0 .. 1023 ). So I'd calculate *180UL / 1024.

Comment: I got it working, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience in Arduino but I think you mustn't set `pinMode(potenMeter, INPUT);` for an analog input. Also keep in mind `A4` don't have to be pin number 4 of your board.

Comment: ** It's not an Arduino**,  Particle Photon reference says 
` Before 0.5.3 Note: do not set the pinMode() with analogRead(). `

Answer (score 0):

> analogRead(potenMeter)/4095

is an integer division and returns 0 usually.

Default is int arithmetics.

<sub>On an 8bit Arduino, you'll easily run into an 16 bit integer overflow.</sub>  but this *particle photon* seems to be a 32 bit thing